# How to remove " [ " symbol from " [19/Mar/2020:05:57:09 " string using sed or awk?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How to remove **`[`** from " **`[19/Mar/2020:05:57:09`** " using `sed` or `awk`?

I need to remove "`[`" from date and time from log file .

Comment: There are many log file parsers which do this and *much* more. If you are not specifically trying to reinvent a better wheel, starting from how to hold an item between your fingers, perhaps use existing tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here some solutions:

```bsh
# Remove with tr and write changes to second file
tr -d '[' < file > file_edited

# Remove with sed and write changes to second file
sed 's/\[//' file > file_edited

# Remove with sed and edit the file inplace!
sed -i 's/\[//' file
```

Note, `tr` solution will remove all `[` in your file, `sed` solutions will delete the first `[` for each line. If that is not exactly what you want, you need to edit your question and give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to delete `[` if you're confident that `[` will appear at the starting of the string and write the output to a file using [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html).

```
cut -b2- input_file | tee output_file
```